# What does error "Passing argument N of 'functionName ' from incompatible pointer type" mean?

Tags: c, unix, warnings

I'm doing a client-server game.
I tested the code in Visual Studio and it works really fine but in linux it gives me some warnings.

warning 1:

> Passing argument 6 of 'movimentos' from incompatible pointer type

declaration of movimentos:

```
msg movimentos(labirinto *l, msg msg, char comando[],
    jogadores *jogador, int total_jog, jogadores lista[],
    monstros lista_monst[5], objetos lista_obj[])
```

In main:

```
msg = movimentos(l, msg, comando, &jogador_aux, total_jog,
    &lista, lista_monstros, lista_obj);
```

In the same function also have the warning:

> expected "`structed jogadores *`" but argument is of type "`struct
>   jogadores (*)[10]`"

Comment: try `&lista` change to `lista`. also `msg` : The same variable name and type name should not be used.

Comment: that resolve the first warning, the struct jogadores (*)[10] stills here

Comment: if i do 'jogador_aux' it gives me an error

Comment: show error message and declare `jogador_aux` part.

Comment: argument of type "jogadores" is incompatible with parameter of type "jogadores *". in the function i've got jogadores *jogador because I need to return the changes made in the function

Comment: It seems to be inconsistent. case `argument is of type "struct jogadores (*)[10]"` then remove `&`. case `argument of type "jogadores"` then add `&`. BTW Do defined type `"jogadores"` ? show declare `jogador_aux` part

Comment: jogadores jogador_aux;

Comment: `struct jogadores jogador_aux;` ... pass `&jogador_aux`

Comment: struct jogadores is the same as jogadores...forget it, it will remain with the warning. thanks anyway

Comment: you need `typedef struct jogadores jogadores;` before use type `jogadores`.

Comment: You'd do everyone a favour if you presented an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and if you presented the exact error message.  (The compiler did not say _expected "`structed jogadores *`" but argument is of type "`struct
  jogadores (*)[10]`"_ because the keyword is `struct` and not `structed`.)  The message says you have a `struct jogadores varname[10];` and you pass `&varname` (pointer to an array) instead of `varname` (pointer to an element of the array) to the function.  Don't apply `&` to array names in general.

Comment: BLUEPIXY I know, and I've got it in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The message says you have a `struct jogadores varname[10];` and you pass `&varname` (pointer to an array) instead of `varname` (pointer to an element of the array) to the function. Don't apply `&` to array names in general. – Jonathan Leffler